# Need some help making a promise function to use a .then

Tags: javascript, promise

I am currently working on a "pre made" project, so I am trying not to change too much of it.

I have a promise function that calls an API and get an array of objects, when creating a map, but it takes too much and it is called everytime a map needs to be created:

```
self.getStoreMapById = function(mapsId) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $http.get("/api/stores/"+mapsId+'/map')
      .then(function (response) {
        deferred.resolve(response);
      });
      return deferred.promise;
    }
```

(This is how it gets called:

```
Stores.getStoreMapById(CONFIG.map.id).then(function(mapResp){
```

So, to avoid waiting a lot of time, I am calling that function once, when the app begins and save the data in 3 different global variables

```
if(maplevel1 == undefined ){
            Stores.getStoreMapById(24).then(function(mapResp){
                maplevel1 = mapResp.data;
            });
        } //same for maplevel2 and 3
```

now, what I want to do is, instead of using this Stores.getStoreMapById to call it everytime I need to create a map, I want to have a function that checks the id and assing the data to another var:

```
if(mapsId == "24"){
            data = maplevel1;
        }
        if(mapsId == "23"){
            data = maplevel2;
        }
        if(mapsId == "21"){
            data = maplevel3;
        }
```

Is there a way to write that in a promise function so I can call:

```
assingMap(CONFIG.map.id).then(function(mapResp){
```

and keep the rest of the code unchanged?

Thanks!

Comment: Avoid the [deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you return a *resolved promise* containing the map:

```
function assignMap(mapsId) {
    var map = /*...find the map in your variables...*/;
    return $q.resolve(map); // With ES2015's promises, this would be
                            // `return Promise.resolve(map);`
}
```

That uses [`$q.resolve`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#resolve) to get a pre-resolved promise. (This is an alias for `$q.when`; it's there to maintain naming consistency with ES2015's `Promise.resolve(value)`.)

A key aspect of promises is that the `then` callback is *always* called asynchronously, even if the promise is already resolved, so code using this won't suddenly get different timing than it used to (other than that the delays will be shorter).

---

Re the "find the map in your variables" part, while you *could* use the long `if/else if` sequence you listed, you probably instead want to use a map of maps:

```
var maps = Object.create(null);
maps[24] = maplevel1; // You can do away with the maplevel1, maplevel2,
maps[23] = maplevel2; // and maplevel3 variables entirely if you create
maps[21] = maplevel3; // the map in the code getting these up front
```

Then:

```
var map = maps[mapsId];
```